# Subtracting a larger binary number from a smaller binary number

Tags: binary

Is it possible to subtract a larger binary number from a smaller one ***column wise*** . For example subtracting 1000 from 0111 ? I always use the 2s complement but is it possible to do it column wise ?

Comment: Yes. The very same way as decimal. You subtract the smaller one from the bigger one and add `-` to the result. Since you don't use 2's complement or similar, there is no special coding for negatives, so you will just have -0001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to do it by hand like you did in elementary school, then yes. Borrow an imaginary 2 (10b) from the imaginary column to the left of the number. For example, here's your problem:

$$
\begin{matrix}
    & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    - & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

and here's what you have after borrowing a 2 from the imaginary fifth bit (sixteen's place):

$$
\begin{matrix}
      & 10 \\
      & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    - & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

10b - 1b is 1b, so the answer is 1111b, or -1 in two's complement -- exactly what you'd expect if you subtract 8 from 7.

This still works if you need to borrow from a smaller place. This:

$$
\begin{matrix}
    & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    - & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

becomes:

$$
\begin{matrix}
      & 1 & 10 \\
      & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    - & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

which is 1110b (-2) -- again, exactly what you'd expect if you subtract 5 from 3.